# Why is every exception a system exception?

Tags: c#, .net

since this morning, every exception in my C# web application in Visual Studio 2012 is a System exception, with no details except "_COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766". No stack trace, no line number. Debugging, watching line by line, I can see that the underlying causes are the usual stuff, null reference exceptions in my crappy code, nothing exotic. But unless I can get back the detailed exception message, with stack trace and line number, I'm going to fix one bug a day.

Im running VS2012 version 11.0 on windows 7 professional SP1. I've tried closing and opening the solution, deleting and regenerating the bin and restarting the machine. I'm running out of ideas. Can anyone help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you debugging in `Debug` or `Release` mode?

Comment: If you have the following piece of code: `private static readonly RegexPattern = "...";` and that pattern is invalid then you generate COMPlusExceptionCode-exceptions when the containing class if initially loaded. On the other hand, you'll need to use a debugger to find out what unhandled exception is getting thrown. Debug + Exception, tick Thrown box to make the debugger stop when the exception is raised.

Comment: This really is not enough information. Does it happen for every exception in that project? Do you have any error handling in place? Does it happen if you throw a derived exception in Application_Start of your Global.asax? What change caused this behavior to appear? The _"since this morning"_ part of the problem causes me to think this could be solved by rolling back either your code or your machine to yesterday.

Comment: @user, bad news: `-532462766` is `0xE0434352`. It's the exception code for a fatal error in the 4.0 CLR. Something is apparently crashing the CLR when a managed exception occurs. That won't be easy to solve, let alone fix.

Comment: There are different reasons for low-level exceptions to happen, do you have an database or network connection? Did it happen after you made changes to the code or out of the blue?

Comment: Check your machine.config file is not corrupt, and is valid xml.

Comment: Machine.config located and checked. Nothing remarkable. Valid XML.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is raised, click on the "Open exception settings" link. Make sure that the type of exception you want to catch is selected.

[image]

Comment: Tick all of the "Thrown" boxes. That will cause the debugger to stop when the exception is thrown. You might get spammed with unnecessary stuff, but that's okay when you're trying to track down a recalcitrant bug. Also, you can get to this dialog from Debug->Exceptions on the main menu. You don't have to wait for an exception to be thrown.

Comment: This handy tip has let me see quickly where the initial exception occurs. When I step forward from the null reference exception, I still get the low level system exception, with no further clues as to why.